# String from Database into an Array

Tags: php, arrays, string, where-clause

I have a field in my database which holds id's. An example would be: 1,2,3,4,5

I basically need to take that string and make it into 1 array so I can do a query with: `WHERE id IN ($string_array)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP: explode - Manual](https://www.php.net/explode)

```
$string = "1,2,3,4,5";
$array = explode(",", $string);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id IN (".$string.")";
$query = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: That's not quite what I need. That would output it so I would need to do $array[0], $array[1] etc. I need it in one array like array(1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: Your array you mentioned in your original question (represented here by `$string`) is already properly formatted for an SQL `IN` statement...

Comment: But I can't just do IN ($string), it needs to be in an array like array(1,2,3,4,5). I have tried using explode, then looping through and adding to an array but so far haven't been successful. It's pretty frustrating seeing as I have done it before not that long ago.

Comment: @RyanStewart I've updated my answer with an SQL example. In this new case, you wouldn't even need to use `explode()`.

Comment: Yes, I got it working. I'm using a CMS powered by CodeIgniter. I found just exploding the string then doing a db->where_in($array); worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$array = explode(",",$string)
```